# Query list of logins that have logged in the last X days on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, logins

Is there any good query that included internal system objects like sys.dm_exec_sessions or sys.dm_exec_connections that would list logins that have connected to the SQL server over the last X days? 15, 30 days? I am also looking for any other query that may help or related to this.

Comment: Do you have any type of logging turned on? SQL Server do not keep track of successful logins by default.

Comment: is there any logging I can turn on which is native to SQL without turning on any triggers, etc?

Comment: See my answer...

Comment: For both of the answers below, if you start recording all this extra on a really busy system it can cause significant space issues.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned by @Tibor, unless you set up logging or trace you cannot retrieve that information natively. You do not need to use trigger.

### Using SQL Server Management Studio

[Configure Login Auditing (SQL Server Management Studio)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/configure-login-auditing-sql-server-management-studio?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15)
Once you set up above you can query the error log and retrieve the information. You can also save the date in a table. I did describe in [this blog post](http://sqlworldwide.com/reading-all-available-sql-error-logs/) how to read from the error log.

### Using Extended Event Trace

[Audit Login Event Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/event-classes/audit-login-event-class?view=sql-server-ver15)

The Audit Login event class indicates that a user has successfully logged in to Microsoft SQL Server. Events in this class are fired by new connections or by connections that are reused from a connection pool.

Steve Jones explained in detail in his blog post: [Tracking Logins with Extended Events](https://voiceofthedba.com/2015/12/16/tracking-logins-with-extended-events/)

Comment: i did turn on login auditing for successful logins, restarted sql server, but when i query using the statement you provided in your blog post, i get no results. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you see the successful login events in your error log? Did you change the value of '@searchString1' and '@searchString2' in my script?

Comment: changing the @searchString1 value did the trick and i can now see the results

Comment: If I answered the result to your satisfaction, do you mind mark the answer as accepted so other users can take benefit?

Answer (score 3):

OK, so no logging turned on at this point. First step is to turn on the type of logging that suits you. Ones that come to mind are:

- Turning on the logging of also successful logins in the registry, using
  SSMS. As described by @SqlWorldWide in another answer. This goes to the EventLog, and also the errorlog file.
- Using XE trace. Again, already explained by @SqlWorldWide.
- Using Server Audit functionality (which is build on XE). Using XE
  directly is probably more flexible for your purposes, but perhaps
  Server Audit can give you insights/info/functionality that using XE
  directly don't have.
- Using the old trace engine, "SQL Trace". This is deprecated, so I
  wouldn't go this route.
- Using Logon Triggers. Your trigger would not most likely insert a row into a table, which you later query.

It is difficult for us to recommend one over the other (except that I don't recommend the old trace engine). Only you know what you are more comfortable with and your requirements. Using any of the XE based methods or Logon Triggers feels a bit more robust for me when it comes to querying the data.

For the XE based methods, you can query a trace file involving some XQuery. Below is an example of a SQL query containing XQuery to parse the XML into columns. Not directly based on an audit trace, but it gives you an idea.

```
--XML from file
SELECT CAST(event_Data AS xml) AS event_data 
FROM sys.fn_xe_file_target_read_file('R:\SqlStatements*.xel', NULL, NULL, NULL)

--Each event is one row

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #myXeData

SELECT CAST(event_Data AS XML) AS StatementData
INTO #myXeData
FROM sys.fn_xe_file_target_read_file('R:\SqlStatements*.xel', NULL, NULL, NULL)

SELECT * FROM #myXeData


--Use XQuery to transform to table. 
SELECT 
 StatementData.value('(event/@name)[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS event_name
,StatementData.value('(event/@timestamp)[1]', 'datetime2(0)') AS time_stamp
,StatementData.value('(event/action[@name="database_name"]/value)[1]','nvarchar(128)') AS database_name_
,StatementData.value('(event/data[@name="duration"]/value)[1]','bigint') / 1000 AS duration_ms
,StatementData.value('(event/data[@name="cpu_time"]/value)[1]','bigint') /1000 AS cpu_ms
,StatementData.value('(event/data[@name="physical_reads"]/value)[1]','bigint') AS physical_reads
,StatementData.value('(event/data[@name="logical_reads"]/value)[1]','bigint') AS logical_reads
,StatementData.value('(event/data[@name="row_count"]/value)[1]','bigint') AS row_count
,StatementData.value('(event/data[@name="statement"]/value)[1]','nvarchar(50)') AS statement_
FROM #myXeData AS evts
--ORDER BY time_stamp
ORDER BY duration_ms DESC
```